# How to copy data within case-set in case control study using SPSS?

Tags: statistics, spss

I'm doing a case-control study about ovarian cancer. I want to do stratified analyses for the different histotypes but haven't found a good way of doing it in SPSS. I was thinking about copying the information about the diagnoses from the cases to the controls, but I don't know the proper syntax to do it.

So - what I want to do is to find the diagnosis within the case-control pair, copy it, and paste it into the same variable for all the controls within that pair. Does anyone know a good way to do this?

ID = unique ID for the individual, casecontrol = 1 for case, 0 for control, caseset = stratum, ID for each matched group of individuals.

My dataset looks like this:

```
ID | casecontrol | caseset | diagnosis
1  |     1       |    1    |     1
2  |     0       |    1    |     0
3  |     0       |    1    |     0
4  |     0       |    1    |     0
5  |     1       |    2    |     3
6  |     0       |    2    |     0
7  |     0       |    2    |     0
8  |     0       |    2    |     0
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
ID | casecontrol | caseset | diagnosis
1  |     1       |    1    |     1
2  |     0       |    1    |     1
3  |     0       |    1    |     1
4  |     0       |    1    |     1
5  |     1       |    2    |     3
6  |     0       |    2    |     3
7  |     0       |    2    |     3
8  |     0       |    2    |     3
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your example, in each value of `caseset` you have one line with `diagnosis` equals some positive number, and in the rest of the lines `diagnosis` equals zero (or is missing?).

If this is true, all you need to do is this:

```
aggregate out=* mode=add overwrite=yes /break=caseset /diagnosis=max(diagnosis).
```

The above command will overwrite the original data, so make sure you have that data backed up, or use a different name for the aggregated data (eg `/FullDiagnosis=max(diagnosis)`  .